# How to animate a chain of segments together with python in Maya

Tags: python, animation, maya

I'm planning to generate a flower in Maya2016 where the leafs are not flexible, but they are built up by 4-5 segments connected to each other. I already have the python script which gets a segment as an input parameter and generates the leaf. (And also generates multiple leafs in a circle.)

Now the question is, how to animate it. I'm new in maya animation. I've found a few example how to do basic things like rotation or transformation with python. But what I wish to have is a realistic movement where the segments are moving how they should be.

My idea is to generate a "skeleton" bone and joint point for every segment. And then I wish to animate the skeleton.

1. Do you think it's a good way of animating the leaf?
2. How can I set up the skeleton?
3. How can I animate a skeleton?

(For the last two, I expect a good source like a blogpost, but I also wish to know if my entire concept is good or not.)

Thanks!